# Executar código PHP dentro de uma condição jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma janela modal que ao abrir, mostra a opção de clicar em um outro botão, que diz sim ou não.

Se eu clicar em sim, eu pretendo destruir a sessão do PHP.

Como posso fazer isso dentro do código jQuery que abre a janela modal?

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#modalLogout').click(function(){
          $('#yes').click(function(){
               // preciso de destruir a sessão <?php session_destroy(); ?>
          });
     });
});
```

Tentei usar:

```
$(this).load("destroy.php");
```

E enviar para uma página PHP mas não funcionou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode redirecionar para sua página `destroy.php` que provavelmente esta destruíndo a sessão e fazendo outro redirecionamento para a tela de login.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#modalLogout').click(function(){
          $('#yes').click(function(){
              window.location = "destroy.php"
```

Se você for usar Ajax, você precisa recuperar o `destroy.php` precisa te retornar algo para o JavaScript saber qual o estado atual da página e fazer o que for necessário, mostrar uma mensagem ou redirecionar o usuário para algum lugar.

Comment: Aqui não funcionou, ele faz o redirecionamento para o destroy.php mas quando volto na página a sessão continua ativa...Também reparei que se eu inserir <?php session_destroy(); ?> dentro do link do botão do modal ele destrói a sessão, mas isso não pode ser porque ele está em um local onde não posso fazer isso, pois vai-me implicar em outra parte do código, por isso queria dentro do jquery.

Comment: Então você não esta destruíndo a sessão, pode compartilhar esse arquivo?

Comment: <?php 
     session_destroy();
     header("Location: ../index.php");
 ?>

Comment: E como você fez o redirecionamento para esta página no seu JavaScript?

Comment: Segui o seu exemplo em cima acrescentei o  window.location = "destroy.php" ao meu código jquery

Comment: E você foi redirecionado? Chegou a carregar o arquivo `destroy.php`? Você não precisa colocar o `session_start()` antes de chamar o `session_destroy()`?

Comment: Resolvi o problema com o seu exemplo, a sessão do PHP não estava devidamente setada, por isso a página de destroy.php não funcionou!